# Why are oracles Hermitian by construction?

Tags: quantum-gate

$\newcommand{\qr}[1]{|#1\rangle}$In [this lecture](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quantum-concepts-10-oracles?view=qsharp-preview), it is nicely explained how to define an operator that computes a function $f(x)$.  I know how to implement such operators.  (We just define $O\qr{x}\qr{y} = \qr{x}\qr{y \oplus f(x)}$.)

However, it it said in the lecture that this effectively proves $O = O^\dagger$ and I fail to see it so clearly.  It says $O = O^\dagger$ **by construction**.  How can I see that so clearly as it is implied?

Comment: Just apply O a second time on your definition.

Comment: Brilliant!  That's definitely an answer: it now hits me that $f(x) \oplus f(x) = 0$.  Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Showing that $O=O^\dagger$ is equivalent to showing that $O^2=\mathbb{I}$. In other words,
$$
O^2|x\rangle|y\rangle=|x\rangle|y\rangle
$$
for all $x$ and $y$.

To show this, we start from the definition of the oracle
$$
O|x\rangle|y\rangle=|x\rangle|y\oplus f(x)\rangle
$$
and apply $O$ again:
$$
O^2|x\rangle|y\rangle=O|x\rangle|y\oplus f(x)\rangle=|x\rangle|y\oplus f(x)\oplus f(x)\rangle=|x\rangle|y\rangle
$$
as required (since $a\oplus a=0$, and bitwise addition is associative).

Answer (score 5):

Defining such oracles, you may visualize it as many controlled operations, especially $\text{CNOT}$s which is an easy way to build oracles.

We know the effect of the $\text{CNOT}$ is if the control is a 1 then we add 1 into the target (you can see it as part of a function itself but it is meant for one bit representing the output register). 
If we enumerate options on a simple 2-bit example with the first as control we have :
$$\text{CNOT}(00) = 00; \text{CNOT}(01) = 01; \text{CNOT}(10) = 1(0+1)=11;\text{CNOT}(11) = 1(1+1)=10$$

We know also that we cancel the effect of the CNOT by applying it again. Take the action of a CNOT but now on images from a first CNOT:
$$\text{CNOT}(00) = 00; \text{CNOT}(01) = 01; \text{CNOT}(11) = 1(1+1)=10;\text{CNOT}(10) = 1(0+1)=11$$

So you see that the effect on bits representing the output of your function represented by controlled operations.

The $ \oplus $ symbol illustrate that if I may say so.